# Append my python script to work on the web?

Tags: python

I just finished building a python script that I would like to deploy for my company on the web, however, I have no knowledge on how to do so unfortunately. If someone could help me it would be much appreciated. I've been looking around at Django and Flask but can't seem to understand it well enough.

What my script does:

- Reads addresses from text file
- Cleans + geocodes address
- Returns address

I would like to get this on the web, while keeping it EXTREMELY SIMPLE. All I need is a button where the user can select the text file, or even have a text box where the user can paste in their addresses. That's it, nothing else. Then when the script has finished processing the addresses it will output the cleaned addresses somehow (either directly on page or maybe as a file?)

My Code:

```
from geopy.geocoders import Bing
from geopy.exc import GeocoderTimedOut
import re
geolocator = Bing('API KEY')

failCount = 0
successCount = 0

def cleanAddress(address):
    global failCount
    global successCount

    patterns = [" st", "street", "ave", "avenue", "plz", "ctr", "park", "pl", " plaza ", "way", "grn", "sq", "ln","dr", "ct", "oval", "vlg", "blvd", "boulevard", " ter", "pkwy", "rd", "row", "hwy", "americas", "broadway"]

    address = address.lower().split('\n')[0]
    address = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', ' ', address).lstrip()
    address = re.sub(re.compile(r'^[^0-9]*'), '', address).lstrip()
    if 'plz' in address:
        address = address.replace('plz', 'plaza ', 1)
    if 'hstreet' in address:
        address = address.replace('hstreet', 'h street')
    if 'dstreet' in address:
        address = address.replace('dstreet', 'd street')
    if 'hst' in address:
        address = address.replace('hst', 'h st')
    if 'dst' in address:
        address = address.replace('dst', 'd st')
    if 'have' in address:
        address = address.replace('have', 'h ave')
    if 'dave' in address:
        address = address.replace('dave', 'd ave')
    if 'havenue' in address:
        address = address.replace('havenue', 'h avenue')
    if 'davenue' in address:
        address = address.replace('davenue', 'd avenue')
    regex = r'(.*)(' + '|'.join(patterns) + r')(.*)'
    #print(re.sub(regex, r'\1\2', address).lstrip())
    address = re.sub(regex, r'\1\2', address).lstrip() + " nyc"

    try:
        clean = geolocator.geocode(address)
        x = clean.address
        address, city, zipcode, country = x.split(",")
        address = address.lower()
        if 'first' in address:
            address = address.replace('first', '1st')
        elif 'second' in address:
            address = address.replace('second', '2nd')
        elif 'third' in address:
            address = address.replace('third', '3rd')
        elif 'fourth' in address:
            address = address.replace('fourth', '4th')
        elif 'fifth' in address:
            address = address.replace('fifth', '5th')
        elif ' sixth a' in address:
            address = address.replace('ave', '')
            address = address.replace('avenue', '')
            address = address.replace(' sixth', ' avenue of the americas')
        elif ' 6th a' in address:
            address = address.replace('ave', '')
            address = address.replace('avenue', '')
            address = address.replace(' 6th', ' avenue of the americas')
        elif 'seventh' in address:
            address = address.replace('seventh', '7th')
        elif 'fashion' in address:
            address = address.replace('fashion', '7th')
        elif 'eighth' in address:
            address = address.replace('eighth', '8th')
        elif 'ninth' in address:
            address = address.replace('ninth', '9th')
        elif 'tenth' in address:
            address = address.replace('tenth', '10th')
        elif 'eleventh' in address:
            address = address.replace('eleventh', '11th')
        zipcode = zipcode[3:]
        print(str(address) + ", "+  str(zipcode.lstrip()) + ", " + str(clean.latitude) + ", " + str(clean.longitude))
        successCount += 1
        #print(str(address))
    except AttributeError:
        print('Can not be cleaned')
        failCount += 1
    except ValueError:
        print('Can not be cleaned')
        failCount += 1
    except GeocoderTimedOut as e:
        print('Can not be cleaned')     
        failCount += 1


def main():

    f = open('address.txt')
    for line in f:
        address = line
        cleanAddress(address)

    f.close()
    global failCount
    global successCount
    total = float(failCount + successCount)
    successRate = float(successCount / total) * 100
    print("Success rate: " + str(successRate) + "%")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Try Flask or Django. Learn the basics. Then add your code into it in small pieces. What you're asking is unclear and too broad

Comment: It sounds like what you need is to pay someone to do this.

Comment: Yeah sorry that i'm not being clear. I think you're right cricket. I'm going to spend the time learning either Flask or Django. Is one "easier" than the other or does it come down to preference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is Flask.

You need to take the meat of your script and wrap it around a function that Flask will call when the user visit a given URL on your company's website. I haven't debugged this code so it may contain errors but you will get the idea:

```
from flask import Flask
from myscript import clearAddress

app = Flask("myaddresscleanerapp")

@app.route("/"):
    return """<form action=\"/processit\" method=\"post\">Address<br><input type=\"text\" name=\"cooladdress\"><br>
    <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\"></form>
    """

@app.route("/processit", methods=['POST'])
def dothing():
    address = request.form['cooladdress']
    return cleanAddress(address) # calling your function and returning the results as plain text
```

After all that, you need to start serving your web application like this (from a script or directly from the command-line terminal):

```
export FLASK_APP=addresscleanerweb.py # or what ever you name your python file
flask run --host=0.0.0.0
```

You will have your web app running, now you need to redirect traffic with a proxy on your server to the port your app is listening so people can use the app by accessing to yourcompanywebsite.com, for instance.

Comment: Ok, sorry for the comments. I figured it out. It now works for 1 address. How can I append it so the user can enter all of the addresses into the text box?

Comment: You will need the change the input type of `cooladdress` from to a [`textbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea#Example), the input you will get would be an address per line (if the users enter one address per line), you need to modify your `clearAddress` function you it breaks each line into a iterable list that your code could process.

Comment: here's what I currently have now: http://pastebin.com/eej1TEde

It's not iterating through all the addresses though. It's only processing the first address that I enter.

Comment: @hleggs store the cleaned address on other list and then return that, because you are breaking the loop with that `return` inside the loop `for`

Comment: So instead of returning it each time I would append the address to a list? I'm a bit confused. Could you maybe show me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116284/discussion-between-hleggs-and-shackra).